# Silex programmatically login with custom domain

Tags: php, symfony, silex, symfony-security

I have a few silex applications and there is a subdomain for each app. (app1.example.com, app2.example.com)

I want to manage login process from a main silex single app.

Following code can make programmatically login, but I want to change cookie's domain field.

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
$tokenStorage->setToken($token);
$session->set('_security_' . $providerKey, serialize($token));
# source: https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/comments/3gyhlt/how_do_i_programmatically_login_a_user_in_a/cu2m3sz
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't set cookie for other domain (just your browser don't allow it). What you can do is to redirect user to subdomain and set cookie there.

Comment: The apps are working on same domain (each app working on own subdomain). In this case cookie can be set.

Comment: Yes for sure https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpstate-cookie-03.xml#sane-domain 
>  For example, the user agent will accept a Domain attribute of ".example.com" or of ".foo.example.com" from foo.example.com, but the user agent will not accept a Domain attribute of ".bar.example.com" or of ".baz.foo.example.com".